# How to enforce tomcat server not to share SSL public certificate to clients(Browsers) requesting for it?

Tags: ssl, tomcat

A Certified Domain should be accessible only if SSL public certificate of the domain is already present in client's trust store. If not, client should prompt to import server certificate instead of getting it from tomcat server automatically(Via SSL handshake)

Answer (score 0):

This will not work: the server has no knowledge which CA certificates are known to the client so the server cannot decide what to send to the client. Also, the server can only send a certificate to the client but not make the client import a new root CA - no matter if with or without prompt.

Apart from that it makes no sense: the idea of TLS/HTTPS is that the client will only connect to a server which identity can be verified. If the server can make a client import a new trusted root CA an attacker could do the same and thusman in the middle attacks would be possible.

If one instead just want to know if the client will trust a specific certificate or  not one could include a resource  (image, script...) served with this certificate into a known good HTML page and then check with some script in the page if the resource was loaded successfully. This check could also result in a redirect of the client, for example to some page describing the problem and linking to the correct root CA.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'll rephrase my question -> Server shouldn't share it's SSL public certificate with client during SSL handshake. I'm having two servers which will communicate with each other using SSL. A's public key is stored in B's truststore and vice versa. 
But these domains(A&B) shouldn't be accessible to any other client(Browser/Any client).

Comment: @BhuvaneswariMurugesan: The server has no idea if this is the right client or not. Any authentication of the client with a client certificate will only be done after the server has already provided its certificate. If you really want to make sure that only the correct client will get the servers certificate then you have to find a way to identify the client before the TLS handshake is started - for example based on its source IP address or whatever is suitable for your use case. Also note that certificates are usually not considered secret information.